# REST access to Spring Config Server from non-spring application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Does anyone know if its possible to use configuration values from the spring config server via a REST interface. If so, is there any documentation on the interface? TIA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [official API doc](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config) is hosted on GitHub.

I have used the REST API manually for testing purposes. I found [this sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver) app to be useful.

#### API Resources

```
|  Path                               |  Description                                                        |
| ----------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------- |
|  /{app}/{profile}                   |  Configuration data for app in Spring profile (comma-separated).    |
|  /{app}/{profile}/{label}           |  Add a git label                                                    |
|  /{app}/{profiels}{label}/{path}    |  An environment-specific plain text config file (at "path")         |
```